# split string and put them line after line

Tags: c#, string, list, split

I have a question, how can i split the string and make splitted string show line by line?

String:

```
What is "that" ENUM "No", "Yes", "OK", "Cancel";
```

I want to have DataTable:

```
Name   Type    Comment
"that" ENUM    "No"       // all of them
               "Yes"      // should be
               "OK"       // in the same
               "Cancel"   // cell
```

must be something with `string[] tmpList = tmp.Split(new Char[] { ' ',',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` and then `attributeDEF.Rows.Add(new object[] { tmpList1[1], tmpList1[2], tmpList1[3] + "\n" + tmpList[a]+ "\n"});`

Can someone give me a clue?

Comment: split string? where did `is "that"` disappear?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted? That's almost what you want isn't it?

Comment: sorry instead of "what" is "that"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will generate a row for you:

```
string tmp = @"What is ""that"" ENUM ""No"", ""Yes"", ""OK"", ""Cancel";

string[] tmpList = tmp.Split(new Char[] { ' ',',', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var row = new object[] { tmpList[0], tmpList[3], string.Join("\n", tmpList.Skip(4).ToArray()) };
```

Comment: Wouter: i tried your code, but why it doen't change anything, i got `"No", "Yes", "OK", "Cancel"` in one line

Comment: What do you mean with 'in one line'? The string.Join adds a "\n" to each item

Comment: sorry i made mistake :p, thanks a lot, work great

Comment: I have 1 question more, what if i want `"No""Yes" /n "OK""Cancel"`? it means No,Yes in one line and Ok, Cancel together in another lines?

Comment: You can use Skip and Take to limit the number of items. Skip(4).Take(2) will take only No/Yes. Skip(5).Take(2) will take OK/Cancel.

Comment: so i did like that `string.Join(" - ", tmpList.Skip(4).Take(2)) +"\n"+ string.Join(" - ", tmpList.Skip(6).Take(2))` but what if i have many of them?

Comment: Then you would have to loop trough them. You can use a foreach or for loop for it.

Comment: i don't know where should i use foreach, tried to loop it but got problem. Should i loop directly in string.join?

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have as a new question?

Answer (score 1):

If you ask about joining strings for the last cell, then this might be one option:

```
var result = String.Join("\n", tmpList.Skip(4).ToArray());
```

Comment: Incidentally, in .NET 4.0 and beyond the extra `ToArray()` is unnecessary.  .NET 4 adds a form that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` sequence.

Comment: works great, thanks once more